problem in connecting to forti using strongswan gui
I have a forti that uses ipsec to connect.I found out I can use GUI to connect using network-manager-strongswan but when i install it, in its page there is no field for pre shared key


it is obvious that where should i put username and password(honestly at this point i'm not even sure about that). but where should i put pre shared key. and what is Identity should i fill it?
I put psk at identity section but this log came in syslog
2024-10-27T14:06:33.820094+03:30 amg charon-nm: 15[IKE] retransmit 1 of request with message ID 0
2024-10-27T14:06:33.820241+03:30 amg charon-nm: 15[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.1.77[42001] to x.x.x.x[500] (1128 bytes)
2024-10-27T14:06:41.020987+03:30 amg charon-nm: 13[IKE] retransmit 2 of request with message ID 0
2024-10-27T14:06:41.027822+03:30 amg charon-nm: 13[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.1.77[42001] to x.x.x.x[500] (1128 bytes)
2024-10-27T14:06:53.981309+03:30 amg charon-nm: 12[IKE] retransmit 3 of request with message ID 0
2024-10-27T14:06:53.981536+03:30 amg charon-nm: 12[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.1.77[42001] to x.x.x.x[500] (1128 bytes)
2024-10-27T14:07:17.310079+03:30 amg charon-nm: 11[IKE] retransmit 4 of request with message ID 0
2024-10-27T14:07:17.310352+03:30 amg charon-nm: 11[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.1.77[42001] to x.x.x.x[500] (1128 bytes)

do you have any idea where should i put it?
p.s: also i use cli mode and get exact error but when i use android it was ok. so the credentials don't have problem
